# Get local name of variable issued to function

Tags: python, reflection

want to get name of variable issued from outside.

For example:

```
def process(var):
  print name(var)#prints 'nice_name'

nice_name=1
process(nice_name)
```

Is it even possible in python?

Answer (score 0):

No, as we are just passing a value to the function